# how to sort array of object in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, object

I am not able to sort this array of object. please kindly help.
I am using `usort` for sorting the array.

Also I am getting this error:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in /home/cg/root/128245/main.php on line 7

I need to sort this array by the order of **job_name** attribute of my class.

```
<?php 
$gfg_array =Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [duration] => 04:32:22
            [date] => 13-Jun-2019
            [start_stamp] => 02:29:32
            [type] => implicit
            [job_name] => build-bbjsd
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [change_sets] => Array
                (
                )
                [job_id] =>  # 4156
            [url] => http://www.html.com
            [duration] => 0:39:25
            [test_script] => {"tc_results": [{"status": "pass", "testcase_time": "0:01:06"}]} 
            [date] => 2019-06-13
            [start_stamp] => 9:30:34
            [type] => explicit
            [job_name] => json-dhj
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [duration] => 
            [date] => 
            [start_stamp] => 
            [type] => implicit
            [job_name] => ci-ulp

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => DISABLED
            [duration] => 
            [date] => 
            [start_stamp] => 
            [type] => implicit
            [job_name] => build-c201-qemux86-64
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [duration] => 04:30:30
            [date] => 13-Jun-2019
            [start_stamp] => 02:29:15
            [type] => implicit
            [job_name] => build-fss-image-full-l200-qemux86-64
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [status] => SUCCESS
            [change_sets] => Array
                (
                )

            [job_id] =>  # 4156
            [url] => http://www.html.com
            [duration] => 0:39:25
            [test_script] => {"tc_results": [{"status": "pass", 
            "testcase_time": "0:01:06"}]} 
            [date] => 2019-06-13
            [start_stamp] => 9:30:34
            [type] => explicit
            [job_name] => json-ci-ulp-fss-image-full-l200-qemux86-64
        )
)

function querySort ($x, $y) {
   return strcasecmp($x['job_name'], $y['job_name']);
}

usort($gfg_array, 'querySort');


print_r($gfg_array)
?>
```

Comment: .you can see this link hare is the same answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17364127/how-can-i-sort-arrays-and-data-in-php

Comment: could you please try and help me . From morning onwards I m trying it.

Comment: @Jeevanjyothi what is the code in line 7 ????

Comment: [duration] => 04:32:22
may be that array i need to convert or wht ?

Comment: @Jeevanjyothi i dont know whats your problem, check this out which is working for me https://3v4l.org/duA4U

Comment: @Krish yes kudos.but see my array format is different . how did u convert it.dts y its not working. you have used qoute for key and value .how did you convert it?or statically u converted it

Comment: @Krish PLEASE answer.thanks

Comment: This looks like an output from a `print_r()` call, that's not how you define an array.  That's the syntax error.

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin i got this from mongo find.then i did json_decode and encode and got above data

Comment: @Jeevanjyothi Well, that's not an output from `json_decode()`, it's from a `print_r()` call, you can't assing a result from `print_r()` to a variable.

Comment: ok tommow in ofc will try.thanks @Rikudou_Sennin

Comment: @Jeevanjyothi, @Rikudou gave you maximum possible answers, try using output of `json_decode()` not `print_r()`

Comment: @Rikudou_Sennin Its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Use [usort](https://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.
You need to create a rule that your objects can be compared with each other.
It is how it's used:

```
function compareObjects( $a , $b )
{
    return strcmp( $a->job_name , $b->job_name );
}

usort( $gfg_array , "compareObjects" );
```

Also you have a syntax error in your code and you need to set array values as strings as below:

```
<?php 
$gfg_array =Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [status] => "SUCCESS"
            [duration] => "04:32:22"
            [date] => "13-Jun-2019"
            [start_stamp] => "02:29:32"
            [type] => "implicit"
            [job_name] => "build-bbjsd"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [status] => "SUCCESS"
            [change_sets] => Array
                (
                )
                [job_id] =>  "# 4156"
            [url] => "http://www.html.com"
            [duration] => "0:39:25"
            [test_script] => {"tc_results": [{"status": "pass", "testcase_time": "0:01:06"}]} 
            [date] => "2019-06-13"
            [start_stamp] => "9:30:34"
            [type] => "explicit"
            [job_name] => "json-dhj"
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [status] => "SUCCESS"
            [duration] => ""
            [date] => ""
            [start_stamp] => ""
            [type] => "implicit"
            [job_name] => "ci-ulp"

    [3] => Array
        (
            [status] => "DISABLED"
            [duration] => ""
            [date] => ""
            [start_stamp] => ""
            [type] => "implicit"
            [job_name] => "build-c201-qemux86-64"
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [status] => "SUCCESS"
            [duration] => "04:30:30"
            [date] => "13-Jun-2019"
            [start_stamp] => "02:29:15"
            [type] => "implicit"
            [job_name] => "build-fss-image-full-l200-qemux86-64"
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [status] => "SUCCESS"
            [change_sets] => Array
                (
                )

            [job_id] =>  "# 4156"
            [url] => "http://www.html.com"
            [duration] => "0:39:25"
            [test_script] => {"tc_results": [{"status": "pass", 
            "testcase_time": "0:01:06"}]} 
            [date] => "2019-06-13"
            [start_stamp] => "9:30:34"
            [type] => "explicit"
            [job_name] => "json-ci-ulp-fss-image-full-l200-qemux86-64"
        )
)

function querySort ($x, $y) {
   return strcasecmp($x['job_name'], $y['job_name']);
}

usort($gfg_array, 'querySort');


print_r($gfg_array)
?>
```

Comment: is that array is correct.when am trying to run its showing :PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ')' in /home/cg/root/128245/main.php on line 7

Comment: I guess you're using `=>` instead of `->`

Comment: am not using from mongo its coming

Comment: I don't get what your problem is.

Comment: when i am using $gfg_array1 =Array
(
      Array
        (
        'score' => '100', 
       'name' => 'b', 
       'subject' => 'Data Structures'
        ),
     Array
        (
        'score' => '100', 
       'name' => 'a', 
       'subject' => 'Data Structures'
        )
);  sorting is working fine

Comment: but  for $gfg_array =Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [score] => 100
            [name] => b
            [subject] => Data Structures
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [score] => 100
            [name] => a
            [subject] => Data Structures
        )

); sorting is not working

Comment: Your Array structure is wrong in the second case. Why don't you use it like the first case that works?

Comment: You need to add double quotes before ` SUCCESS` and time and other values you're adding to the array.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this function..

````
    function multisortByKeyValue( $k, $arr ) {
        $ids   = array();
        $index = 1;

        foreach ( $arr as $key => $row ) {
            $ids[ $key ] = intval( $row[ $k ] ) . '-' . $index . '-' . $key;
            $index ++;
        }

        natsort( $ids );

        $arr = array_merge( $ids, $arr );

        return $arr;
    }
```
````

Comment: what do i need to pass in multisortKeyValue()? my array or wht?